# Uninitialized constant RUBY_PATCHLEVEL (NameError) while running Homebrew on linux

Tags: linux, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew on linux. I followed the instructions at https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew and installed homebrew with no errors but when i try to execute, i am getting the below error.

```
upendra_35@172 Softwares]$ ~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew
/home/upendra_35/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:38: uninitialized constant RUBY_PATCHLEVEL (NameError)
    from /home/upendra_35/.linuxbrew/Library/brew.rb:15:in `require'
    from /home/upendra_35/.linuxbrew/Library/brew.rb:15
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linuxbrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew) requires Ruby 1.8.6 or newer. Ruby 1.8.6 is the version where the `RUBY_PATCHLEVEL` constant was defined, as well as [other features that Linuxbrew needs anyway](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/pull/15).

Ruby 1.8.6 came out in March 2007, so this shouldn't be a very onerous requirement. If you have a very old system (CentOS 5?) you'll need to install a more recent version of Ruby. [RVM](http://rvm.io/) is an easy way to install Ruby and Ruby libraries.